# How to change the background color of a div in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I have been trying to figure out how to change the background color of 2 divs but had it right the first time I believe. My code is as follows,

```
.maincontentrow {
    width: 960px;
    background-color:#999;
}
```

[The Rest of my code:](http://pastebin.com/qCAWQNES)

The problem I am having is I am using Dreamweaver and the background color change shows up in design mode but not in live mode or when I run it from the browser. I've Googled this high and low and it appears my code is correct. It just wont show the color change in live or in browser. But It does show the change in design mode.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or what I can do to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code. You say two div's but we don't see any div's here. It's tough to help you without seeing what you see :)

Comment: Which browser are you trying with? Some older versions of IE does not support shorthand colors.

Comment: I am damn sure your `.maincontentrow` has nested floated elements\

Comment: Here is the entire code. I've not cleaned up the CSS completly so some of it is on 1 line some is not. http://pastebin.com/qCAWQNES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't added any element inside the div. Place some text inside it or add `height: 50px;` in CSS

Comment: This worked. And I can understand the concept of why it worked. I figured that the content nested in this div would count as 'content' thus giving it a background. What's my best option? Manually do this? I would prefer it so that it would automatically fill based on the content nested inside it.

Comment: The child elements will automatically find a background as its parents. I am not sure what is your objectives here

Comment: For example. If i was in the code and kept pressing enter or <br> the div would keep getting bigger or would have more height. It would expand automatically. In the way you showed I have to set the height manually rather than the div taking into consideration the content already in it.

Comment: Pretty sur I just found it. It needed overflow: auto;

Comment: Thanks for your help I've accepted your answer. We got it fixed now =)

Answer (score 0):

Try `background : #999;` or `background-color:#999999` or `background-color:rgb(153,153,153);`